# The requested URL /survivors_vocational_resources/public_html/survivors_resources/about was not found on this server.How do I fix this?

Tags: javascript, html, apache, localhost

I am trying to build an HTML/CSS and JavaScript website as a demo to submit with a job application as an entry level coder and I am unable to get my "about" page to work. My index.html page works fine, but when trying to make a link to the about.html page or any of the other pages I am making (by borrowing some of my material from another site I made that IS working on the local server), I get this error saying "Not Found

The requested URL /survivors_vocational_resources/public_html/survivors_resources/about was not found on this server. "

and I don't know how to fix it. Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Upstate NY/Northwestern PA Trafficking Survivors Vocational Support Group</title>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
   <body class= "body-home" id="home">
     <header class="topbar">
       <div class="topbar-inner">
         <div class="container">
           <ul class="nav">
              <li>
                <a href="/survivors_resources/about" class="first">About Us</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/jacqueline/prototype" class="first">Prototype and Timer Examples</a>
             </li>
             <li>    
                <a href="/jacqueline/updates" class="first">Updates</a>
             </li>
             <li>
                <a href="/jacqueline/contact-us" class="first">Contact Us</a>
             </li>
          </ul>
       </div>
   </div>
   <h1>Rebuilding Lives Through Learning to Code</h1>





 <script type="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js">  </script>
 <script type="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.13/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
 <script src="appscripts.js"></script>
 </body>
```

Comment: The link you mention makes reference to the first in the list. It is missing the first slash (/) that the rest of the links have. Might this be the problem? Without more info about the server directory structure, it is hard to say more.

Comment: I already previously tried that but it still didn't work for me, delCano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After literally trying everything I could think of, I finally found the problem after conferring with a senior dev who suggested I check the file perms and reset them if needed. Apparently, Apache (unlike a Rails server) does not acknowledge the sandboxing of various directories and when you change the file perms in ONE file in a subdirectory (i.e. folder) under the public_html directory, and so when I changed file perms in the file public_html/php_stuff/girldevit laast week for a class assignment in Beginner Level PHP, that was enough to throw everything else in my public_html directory off. So I finally found the fix for it: I ran the `ls -la` command in terminal to check file perms, then in the public_html directory, I ran the command: `sudo usermod -a -G www-data <myusername>`, which fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The link does not show the .html on about ... try:

```
<a href="survivors_resources/about.html" class="first">About Us</a>
```

Comment: You've verified the link above which I am assuming is in the index.html file, as well as the actual file name `about.html` as it exists on the server?

Comment: Additionally, what is the actual path to the index.html after the server name.  In your error, I am seeing `/survivors_vocational_resources/public_html/` and typically public_html is a back-end reference.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "actual path" rformal? This is the full path for it
`public_html/survivors_resources/about` (which I do have as I took off the .html part).

Comment: Actual path refers to the path used behind the scenes.  There typically is  a path that is referenced when the URL is accessed.  So, when you go to http://www.somedomain.com ... on the server the actual path where index.html and about.html live might be C:\server\public_html\files\.  Referenced in a URL, it would become http://www.somedomain.com/index.html  ... which could be simplified to `<a href='index.html'>` or `<a href='/index.html'>` ... by seeing the full path the index.html, we might be able to determine the correct link to about.html ...

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with the basics.
I assume you do have the files of the website under a directory, let's say (I am assuming you work on Windows):

> `c:\Blablabla\survivors_vocational_resources\public_html\`

You have a webserver with a root directory also such as: `c:\Blablabla\survivors_vocational_resources\public_html\`.

Then, for example, if you want to access a file which is in

> `c:\Blablabla\survivors_vocational_resources\public_html\survivors_resources\about.html`,

you must substract the Webserver root from the full path, which would leave you with

> `/survivors_resources/about.html`

(webservers always use / instead of \ as directory separators).

So now, depending of your actual directory tree and server configuration, you can try to find the errors in your code.

PS: If you are not using a webserver but browsing your hard drive directly, you can either use the full paths: `c:\Blablabla\survivors_vocational_resources\public_html\survivors_resources\about.html` or relative paths, which depend on your origin. For example, to go from `c:\Blablabla\survivors_vocational_resources\public_html\jaqueline\index.html` to `c:\Blablabla\survivors_vocational_resources\public_html\survivors_resources\about.html`, you could use `..\survivors_resources\about.html` (.. goes up one directory, and we're using anti-slashes () because we are using the native windows filesystem and not a webserver).

I hope I expained myself. In any case, this is very basic, you should start learning about directory traversal before starting to code.